# What's the Family Trainer Dancing Mat Controller for?

Tags: controllers, nintendo-wii

There is some kind of weird dance controller for the Wii.

[image]

What's this for? What games are compatible with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Family Trainer" is a Japanese game by Namco, and could be considered a competitor to the Wii Fit.  Here's a video of the game in action:

In the US, the game was retitled ["Active Life: Outdoor Challenge"](http://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/xg6sb1evyUisUB2Di9tk9qAXvwa7qfU7)

The controller also works with the game's two sequels, [Active Life: Extreme Challenge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Life:_Extreme_Challenge) and [Active Life: Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Life:_Explorer).

It also seems like this controller uses the GameCube ports on the top of the Wii to connect, which would make it incompatible with the [Wii Family Edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/64811/13845), which lacks them.