# Which Wii console version has GameCube compatibility?

Tags: nintendo-wii, backwards-compatibility, nintendo-gamecube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Wii consoles can play GameCube games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64788/what-wii-consoles-can-play-gamecube-games)

I've been surfing the Internet looking for a Wii system but I want to make sure I get one that can play GameCube titles.

I've read on conflicting reports indicating that some versions are compatible and others are not.

How can I tell which system has retro compatibility? Links to amazon would be awesome.

Comment: This looks very similar to this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/64788/15772

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original Wii can play GameCube games. You just need enough GameCube controllers - one per player. There are even ports at the top of the box for the controllers and memory cards to fit. Just pop the disc in the slot. You will have to have/find an early console, later models had these ports removed.

The Wii U can also play GameCube games - [but download versions only](http://wiiudaily.com/wii-u-backwards-compatibility/) so if you were hoping to keep playing the games you already own, you're out of luck.

Comment: Not all Wii consoles have those ports. Nintendo stopped producing them at some point. If you buy a new Wii you won't have the ports. He needs to find a used one (an older version) that has them.

Comment: @PanagiotisPalladinos - ah. Didn't know that. Will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out considering Wii U + GameCube: http://www.ign.com/blogs/ffvii_valentine/2012/01/19/wii-u-should-support-gamecube-controllers-heres-how

But mainly check this link out: http://infiniteneslives.com/

You could make a request in the second site for a "custom" solution.

For the Original Wii you wanna find one with GCN ports on it. At some point Nintendo stopped producing Wiis with those ports. So you wanna find a used one that has them.